# How to do aggregation with "secondary" read mode in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoid

How can I make this aggregation read with `secondary` mode? Here's an example:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name, type: String
  field :status, type: String
  field :balance, type: Float
end


User.collection.aggregate(
  {
    '$group' => {
      'status' => '$status',
      'total' => { '$sum' => '$balance' }
    }
  }
)
```

I believe that I need to add an option `{ read: :secondary }` to this aggregation. But how can I do this?

If I do a simple query, I can add `{ read: :secondary }` option like this:

```
User.extras(read: :secondary)
=> #<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {:read=>:secondary}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
```

I'm using Mongoid 4.0.2

(This `User.extras(read: :secondary).collection.aggregate` doesn't work)

Comment: My understanding was that `.collection` actually gets the `Mongo::Collection` object from the underlying core driver, so any Mongoid settings likely don't get passed through at that point. You can actually set Read Preference on the actual aggregate call itself. `.aggregate([<pipeline>], { :read => :secondary })`. As general you really should beware when setting read preference, as most people who think they "need it" really don't. There is no "guarantee" that a secondary has the latest data. As long as you accept that, it's okay.

Comment: Also note your own call to `.aggregate()` is missing the array `[]` notation around the pipeline. Even for a single pipeline stage, usage without the array notation is discouraged and should be considered deprecated.

Comment: @NeilLunn ```User.collection``` returns ```Moped::Collection``` instance. I can not pass array and hash to ```#aggregate``` method. It allows me to pass only hashes(doesn't matter how many).

Comment: What version of Mongoid is this? All language API's have the very first argument as an array and for a "very long time". I have about 20 answers on this site at a quick glace that all demonstrate this with Mongoid alone. Looking up I see 4.02. That's old, but It still has the API I describe here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `read: { mode: :secondary }` as the second argument to `aggregate`. For example:

```
User.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      '$group' => {
      'status' => '$status',
      'total' => { '$sum' => '$balance' }
    }
  ],
  read: { mode: :secondary }
)
```